# Create a quadratic bezier from vertices of three different circles in Geometry Nodes

Tags: bezier-curves, vertices, geometry-nodes

Im have three circles with the same resolution, and I was wondering how could I take a vertex from each circle and use it to create a quadratic bezier.

For example, take the first vertex of the three circles and make a quadratic bezier with the starting point, middle point and last point. Repeat that for every index.

I tried some different stuffs with the Transfer Attribute node, but the result is not what I was looking for.

This is what I achieved:

[image]

What I want is something like this:

[image]

These are my GeoNodes for it:

[image]

If I substitute the "Integer" node before the transfer attribute nodes for the "Index" node, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can u pls add a sketch how it should look like? Thanks

Comment: @Chris What I want is exactly what I show at the first image, but not just for one vertex, but for all of then.

Comment: @Chris I edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this relatively easily by simply querying a certain position of each of the three circles.

The easiest way to do this is to use the node `Sample Curve`. It will directly provide you with the required positions for your curve.

After you have created your curve, you have two options *(depending on what you really want)*:

### Method 1

You can rotate and instantiate with `Instance on Points` along one of the circles to get exactly the shape you sketched.

If you divide $\pi*2$ by the number of points, you get the angle for a stepwise rotation.

[image]

### Method 2

You can also create a mesh directly from this profile curve by using the node `Curve to Mesh`.

...and of course you can also use this method and remove the superfluous horizontal edges afterwards.

[image]

Here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: This exactly what I'm looking for. I learned how to use the Sample Curve node as well. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

[image]

to get this:

[image]

The quadratic bezierpath has 4 control points for its lowest resolution. So for 3 circles...you didn't define where the points should be. So i just set 2 points on the same spot.

And no, i won't change my answer if you want it another way (unfortunately i made this experience often here that people than "improve" their question to get what they really want, but i think the question shouldn't be changed but then they should ask a new more precise question)